Flutter web build cause 'No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call' in new screen
I call this to initialize Firebase.
Future initializeFirebaseApp() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: DefaultFirebaseOptions.firebaseName,
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  )
      .whenComplete(() => Log().i('Firebase Initialized'))
      .onError((error, stackTrace) {
    Log().e('Firebase Initialize Error: $error $stackTrace');
    return Future.error("");
  });
}

fun main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeFirebaseApp();

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: IAmApp()));
}

And I use AutoRouter.
When I change the screen with context.pushRoute(const PasswordLoginRoute())
And PasswordLoginScreen has FirebaseAuth like this in HookConsumerWidget:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final firebaseAuth = ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
    // ...
  }

@riverpod
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth(FirebaseAuthRef ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance;

And because of that I get No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call.
Should I initialize Firebase every page for web build?

It looks like you passed a custom name when initializing Firebase.
To resolve this do either one of these;

Remove the custom name and allow Firebase to initialize the app with [DEFAULT] name;

await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  )


Retrieve your custom-named Firebase app whenever you need to use any Firebase service.

final firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app(DefaultFirebaseOptions.firebaseName));

